# Calculate the values-sw<n>dp int Android?

Tags: android

Calculate the values-swdp int Android? Can anybody give me a calculation method?
What according to the screen size, dimensions to calculate?
Devices info is :Screen size is 720*1280, Dimensions 4.7?

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer about smallestWidth sw< N >dp in

1. [New Tools For Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html), Android Developers Blog
2. [android:requiresSmallestWidthDp](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest), Android Developers